# Typescript variable to style Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

I would like to pass typescript variable to style, I dont know if it's possible, there is code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let app of data">
    <div class="progress_bar" style="width: {{app.applicationProgress}}%;"></div>
</tr>
```

My app.applicationProgress is set(checked)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `ngStyle` directive. [Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

Updated code:

```
<div class="progress_bar" [ngStyle]="{'width': app.applicationProgress + '%'}"></div>
```